# Getting Intellisense inside <% %> tags

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

For some reason, Intellisense has stopped working inside code blocks (<% %>) in Visual Studio 2010 in both aspx and ascx files. This was working, but I obviously flipped some setting unknowingly.

Anyone run into this before? It's pretty annoying.

Comment: Have you tried closing Visual Studio and then re-opening...

Comment: Yes. Happens every time studio is open

Comment: Are you using Resharper? There's an issue with the Razor view engine, I don't know if it affects WebForms as well.

Comment: Are you using portable areas by any chance? If you are, then check your web.config files are set up correctly for them.

Comment: Wish I could say this is something fancy, but these are just straight up WebForm/Controls for a Sitecore implementation. Also, none of the developers on the project have the issue, so I'm going to rule out web.config (shared via source control)

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense within inline code blocks is hit or miss a lot of times. I've tried to discern some logical reason for it, but there doesn't seem to be one.

I've noticed that it works sometimes if you close and reopen the page, or close and reopen Visual Studio, but I don't know of any sure-fire way to ensure that it works.

Comment: Sort of getting the same feeling.